# Rollapply function to calculate proportion very slow in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of around 180 000 small values (but I am going to scale it up).

```
head(UncertaintyData)
[1] 0.95 0.99 0.06 0.02 1.00 1.00
```

What I am doing is simple, I'd like to know the proportion of values within each non-overlapping sliding window which are below a certain value:

```
    proportion_above = function(vec)
    {
      return(sum(vec < 0.1) / length(vec))
    }

        UncertaintyData=rollapply(UncertaintyDataHaploidI1100, 20000, proportion_above,   by=1)

   user  system elapsed 
321.248   0.016 321.322
```

Takes over 100 times faster than calculating the mean of each window.

```
   UncertaintyData=rollapply(UncertaintyDataHaploidI1100, 20000, mean,   by=1)
     user  system elapsed 
  2.144   0.032   2.175
```

why is `proportion_above` so slow and how can I speed it up?

Thanks.

Comment: try `rollsum(v < 0.1, k) / k`

Comment: Can you add a sample of UncertaintyDataHaploidI1100?